# How ping a server which has ICMP blocked

Tags: ping, denial-of-service, icmp

I'm trying to ping a server which has ICMP blocked with normal ping. It's showing:

> Request timed out

Is there any other method to ping it?

Answer (score 15):

I use [Nping](http://nmap.org/nping/), which is packaged with [Nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html). It queries a port of your choosing, for example port 80, and if the port is open, it will receive a response. For example:

```
nping --tcp microsoft.com
```

Comment: That methods gives me `Avg rtt: 97ms` whilst pings are stable around `200msec`. I don't think this is a good method for measuring anything with sub-second accuracy.

Comment: This is a good replacement for ping. I installed via homebrew ([nping is included in nmap](https://nmap.org/nping)) with `brew install nmap` and then had to use `sudo nping --tcp domain.com`

Comment: Use -p for the port option `nping --tcp -p 443 microsoft.com`

Answer (score 1):

That's the idea behind blocking ICMP. You can attempt to identify whether a host is up/down using nmap. http://www.cyberciti.biz/networking/nmap-command-examples-tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

If ICMP is blocked, you can't ping the host in the normal way, however, if it is running an exposed tcp service, you can use [tcping](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php). It sends a SYN, listens for SYN/ACK response as the ICMP Echo equivalent and measures the time required for the transaction.